# Is there a way to integrate Java/Groovy with Haskell using Gradle?

Tags: java, haskell, groovy, gradle

I usually work on projects based on Java/Groovy along with Gradle. 
Now I would like to start introducing in these projects Haskell (at the beginning just as one-off spike scripts only). Initially I can manage them with Cabal but if its usage get more "integrated" with the remaining core base, I would like to be able to manage compiling/test/deployment phases with Gradle.

Is there any plugin/way to manage Haskell with Gradle? I am not talking about Frege (as the only solution I have found googling) but Haskell.

Comment: Some searching seems to suggest that there is not a good Haskell plugin for Gradle yet... writing Gradle plugins can be fun, you should write one for Haskell. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've released a [Gradle Haskell plugin](https://github.com/prezi/gradle-haskell-plugin) last week which may be what you want. The announcement for the release can be found [here](http://vigoo.github.io/posts/2015-04-22-gradle-haskell-plugin.html).

We have been using it the last ~2 months for multiple Haskell projects successfully.